# How do I interpret INT96 represented as a byte[12] array in Java, and convert to DateTime?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, parquet, avro

I'm reading from a parquet file and I noticed per the schema that our dates are being read as INT96 represented as byte[12]. So when reading from the parquet file, a date will look like an Object [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -63, -120, 37, 0].

Does anyone know how I'd go about converting this to a usable format so I could get the date? Or if there's a way I'm supposed to tweak my s3 parquet file reader so I can get the actual date instead of that byte array?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Found an answer.
First casted it to GenericData.fixed, then did
```
byte[] bytes = fixed.bytes();
    // little endian encoding - need to invert byte order
    long timeOfDayNanos =
        Longs.fromBytes(bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
    int julianDay = Ints.fromBytes(bytes[11], bytes[10], bytes[9], bytes[8]);
    long ts = ((julianDay - JULIAN_EPOCH_OFFSET_DAYS) * MILLIS_IN_DAY) + (timeOfDayNanos / NANOS_PER_MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: can you pls quote the source of where you got this from ? I need to do the same and would like to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

- ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(int96Bytes);
  buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
  long nano = buf.getLong();
  int dt = buf.getInt();

  ```
           int l = dt + 68569;
           int n = 4 * l / 146097;
           l = l - (146097*n+3)/4;
           int i = 4000 * (l + 1) / 1461001;
           l = l - 1461*i/4 + 31;
           int j = 80 * l / 2447;
           int k = l - 2447*j/80;
           l = j / 11;
           j = j + 2 - 12*l;
           i = 100*(n-49) + i + l;

           System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of((int) i, Month.of(j), k, 0, 0).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime().plusNanos(nano))
  ```